# Any way to programmatically get a value/setting from Bcdedit.exe, using .NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, command-line, elevated-privileges

When running `bcdedit.exe` from an elevated command prompt, you can see the values of the current BCD settings. I need to read the setting/value of `hypervisorlaunchtype`.

[image: Screenshot]

Does anyone know a way to do this?

I've tried to write the piped output to a tmp file so that I could parse it, but ran into piped output issues due to the fact that `bcdedit.exe` needs to be run from an elevated prompt. Maybe there's a better way?

**Edit:** I forgot to add that I'd like to be able to do this without the end user seeing the Command Prompt at all (i.e. not even a quick flash) is possible.

Comment: Are you trying to get these values from an application which does not run with admin rights?

Comment: I could do it either way, whichever would work best.

Comment: i'd imagine you'd be able to use [Process.StandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, run your Visual Studio as Administrator and try this code in a console application (run the application with debugging):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = @"CMD.EXE";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/C bcdedit";
        p.Start();
        string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        p.WaitForExit();

        // parse the output
        var lines = output.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(l => l.Length > 24);
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            var key = line.Substring(0, 24).Replace(" ", string.Empty);
            var value = line.Substring(24).Replace(" ", string.Empty);
            Console.WriteLine(key + ":" + value);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

However, there is a problem, If you want this to work when launching the application from outside the elevated Visual Studio, you need to configure your application to ask for elevated rights:

On your project, click add new item and select Application Manifest File.

Open app.manifest file and replace this line:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

with this one:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great, but it flashes the command prompt while reading the info from BCDedit.exe. I forgot to mention that I'd like it to remain hidden from the user as I'm making a GUI of sorts for it, and always flashing the command window is icky. =) I updated my question to reflect this. It seems to be an issue with the use of `UseShellExecute`'s value. Any idea on a workaround?

Comment: @J.ScottElblein have you tried using `ProcessStartInfo` and setting the `CreateNoWindow = true`?

Comment: You can also try this: p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;